# `SELECT` Query not working for prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to show all of the users in the users column of my database but nothing is showing up. I want to have a ranking of users based on the number of likes they get. My query looks fine to me but it's not showing anything. No warnings, errors or the output I am calling for. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong ? I've checked all the answers for about an hour, then I tried to use the prepared statements that I already have. But nothing works.

This is the whole page:

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
error_reporting(-1);

require 'includes/header.php';

$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT username, num_likes FROM users WHERE username = ? ORDER BY num_likes DESC ');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $num_likes);

// output data of each row
while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
    
    echo '<div id="rcorners2">';
            
    echo '<p id="p2">' . $username . '</p>';

    echo '<p id="p4">' . $num_likes . '</p>';   
    
    echo'</div>';
    echo'</br>';

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>User's Ranks</title>
<style type="text/css">
    
#rcorners2 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #8c8c8c;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-left: 350px;
}
#p2 {
    float:left;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: -10;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#p4 {
    float:left;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: -1%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That query will select at best only one user. Or non if the username you pass to the query does not exist

Comment: You are also ouputting the result of the query before you output the HTML `<!DOCTYPE html>` and other base parts of the HTML Document. So even if yo uget any rows they will not appear in the document

Comment: @RiggsFolly I declared the username variable at the top of the script and it still doesn't work. Is it secured if I do it this way ? It works exactly how I want it to and it doesn't show errors

Comment: $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT username, num_likes FROM users ORDER BY num_likes DESC ');
 //$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result();
 $stmt->bind_result($username, $num_likes);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are also ouputting the result of the query before you output the HTML `<!DOCTYPE html>` and other base parts of the HTML Document. So even if you get any rows they will not appear in the document

If you output your info in the Document `<body>` it will show on the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>User's Ranks</title>
<style type="text/css">
    
#rcorners2 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #8c8c8c;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-left: 350px;
}
#p2 {
    float:left;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: -10;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#p4 {
    float:left;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: -1%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
error_reporting(-1);
require 'includes/header.php';

$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT username, num_likes 
                        FROM users WHERE username = ? 
                        ORDER BY num_likes DESC ');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $num_likes);

// output data of each row
while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
    echo '<div id="rcorners2">';
    echo '<p id="p2">' . $username . '</p>';
    echo '<p id="p4">' . $num_likes . '</p>';   
    echo'</div>';
    echo'</br>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

You also say you want ALL your users to dispay, so the query may also need changing to get all users where yours gets only one.

```
$result = $con->query('SELECT username, num_likes 
                        FROM users
                        ORDER BY num_likes DESC ');

// output data of each row
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<div id="rcorners2">';
        echo '<p id="p2">' . $row['username'] . '</p>';
        echo '<p id="p4">' . $row['num_likes'] . '</p>';   
    echo'</div>';
    echo'</br>';
```

Comment: Added some code to change the query to get ALL your users

Comment: Is it secure that way ?

Comment: Yes, you are not using any concatenated value in the query, so you have no vector for SQL Injection

Answer (score -1):

you need to initialize a database connection first.

e.g. $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
Refer to : https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp